# Atom editor still let work with merged and deleted branch

Tags: git, github, merge, branch, atom-editor

I needed merge additional branch to main. Github say it's successfully done but Atom still let edit merged and removed branch. What I made incorrect and how to fix it?

I made successfull pull, merged additional branch to main branch and after deleted merged additional branch successfully - all using GitHub. GitHub show I have only 1 branch now and it's main branch but my atom editor still let me switch and edit already deleted additional branch.

I tried fetch and reboot but nothing helped. I also didn't find same theme disscussion here.
[image]

My repository: https://github.com/iuriimigushin/learninghtml

Comment: I found file in git folder of project:

.git\refs\heads<additional branch name>

Should I just delete this file within explorer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by command prompt.

First

```
git checkout master
git merge page-switcher-fix
```

at the end

```
git branch -d page-switcher-fix
```

I hope I could have helped

Answer (score 0):

Seems it's possible to delete removed branch .git\refs\heads in cause I step back by timemachine and bug fixed.
Anyway, best choise is step back by timemachine or same like snapshots in Virtual Machine

Answer (score 0):

A distinction is made between remote and local branches. As you describe your case you deleted your *branch remotely*. For further context please see the code below for the command prompt:

```
# delete branch remotely
git push origin --delete page-switcher-fix
```

And as the solution of [@Mohammad Afshar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17586340/mohammad-afshar) correctly suggests you can delete your *branch locally* as follows:

```
# delete branch locally
git branch -d page-switcher-fix
```